# Why does set() behave so unintuitively in Python?

Tags: python

I don't understand why set() works the way it does...

Let's say we have two lists:

```py
a = [1,2,-1,20,6,210,1, -11.4, 2]
b = [1,2,-1,20,6,210,1,-11.4, 2, "a"]
```

When I run set() on the list of numerics, a, I get a set of unique numerics ordered from smallest to largest. Ok great, that seems intuitive! Haven't found any exceptions yet:

```py
set(a)
Out: {-11.4, -1, 1, 2, 6, 20, 210}
```

What happens if I throw a character in like with list b? Weirdness. The negatives are out of order and so is 6.

```py
set(b)
Out: {-1, -11.4, 1, 2, 20, 210, 6, 'a'}
```

It gets worse though. What if I try to turn those sets back into lists? Pure chaos.

```py
list(set(a))
Out: [1, 2, 6, 210, 20, -11.4, -1]

list(set(b))
Out: [1, 2, 6, 'a', 210, 20, -11.4, -1]
```

As you can see, these lists indeed only have unique values. But have failed to preserve much semblance of the order of the original lists.

**What's going on here and why?**

Comment: I know 'a' is ascii 97, that would put it in numerical ordering, however I dont believe the documentation guarantees the set is ordered.

Comment: Sets, in most languages, are unordered. Any perceived order is a consequence of the implementation and shouldn't be relied on unless the set is explicitly indicated to be ordered.

Comment: btw your list `b` does not contain `-11.4`. And I'm not sure that anything you have asserted is actually true.

Comment: " I get a set of unique numerics ordered from smallest to largest. Ok great, that seems intuitive! " No, it isn't. Your intution is that *sets don't have order*, because python sets are *hash sets*. Any order you happen to see is the result of implementation details.

Comment: It behaves strangely because it hasn't made any promises to behave predictably re: order.  It's an unordered type.  If you want to get order out of a set, try `sorted(set(b))` which will give you a list.

Comment: As everyone has said, the order of sets is not assured, its just coincident. Order also is subjective. If your values are ordered by a stringwise implementation then 100 for example would come before 19 etc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `set` type in python is *not* explicitly ordered.  It can appear ordered based on the implementation, but is not guaranteed to be so.  If you need a ordered representation, you should use something like `sorted(set(input_sequence))` which will return a sorted list after removing the duplicates.  Note that sorting lists with types that are not comparable is not supported without some sort of custom comparator (so you can't sort `['a', 1]` out of the box).

Comment: I'll do you one better: the docs explicitly say "[A set is an unordered collection](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)". Python doesn't just say "this may not be ordered", but that they definitely aren't.